# Как объединить несколько значений в 1 уникальный id?

Tags: postgresql

Такая задача, есть таблица пользователей где у них есть id уникальный и login в виде текста.

Но одни и те же пользователи могут иметь разный логин.

```
    id 35  mysite.ru/oleg655
    id 36  mysite/oleg655
    id 152 MYSITE/oleg655
```

Вот тут пользователь один и тот же oleg655. Но раньше в базу писалась строка которая приходила от веб сервера и в базе для каждой такой записи создавались разные id.

Нужно объединить их и обновить во всех таблицах где они указаны как внешние ключи. 
И вопрос, в зависимых таблицах нужно поставить во внешнем ключе On UPDATE restrict или что?

Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала надо получить какие id в какие преобразовывать. Сделать это можно примерно так:

```
select (string_to_array(login,'/'))[2] as login,
       id as current_id,
       min(id) over(partition by (string_to_array(login,'/'))[2]) as new_id
  from tab
```

Берем минимальный id для каждого логина, как основной. Функцию для выборки логина из строки поправьте сами, по необходимости.

Тогда изменение id в другой таблице будет выглядеть так:

```
with New as(
select (string_to_array(login,'/'))[2] as login,
       id as current_id,
       min(id) over(partition by (string_to_array(login,'/'))[2]) as new_id
  from tab
)
update forUpdate as Old
   set id=New.new_id
  from New
 where Old.id=New.current_id and New.new_id!=New.current_id
```

После того как все таблицы обновлены, останется только удалить ненужные записи из таблицы с логинами.

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1222c/1)

Что касается внешних ключей в таблицах ставьте им те параметры, которые нужны вашему приложению, на замену id на заведомо существующие никакие параметры ключей влияния не окажут.